# Coldspring 2.0 and Fusebox 5.5 (XML)

Tags: coldfusion, fusebox, coldspring

My app uses Fusebox 5.5 and Coldspring 1.2.  I'm trying to migrate to Coldspring 2.0.  In Fusebox_lexicon/coldspring/initialize.cfm there is the following block of code:

```
// set ColdSpring in this fusebox instance's application space 
    fb_appendLine('<cfset myFusebox.getApplication().getApplicationData().#fb_.coldspringfactory# = createObject("component", "coldspring.beans.DefaultXmlBeanFactory").init( defaultProperties="#fb_.defaultproperties#" )/>');    
    fb_.i = 1;
    // load all bean definitions
    for ( fb_.i = 1; fb_.i lte arraylen( fb_.verbInfo.beans ); fb_.i = fb_.i + 1){
        fb_appendLine('<cfset myFusebox.getApplication().getApplicationData().#fb_.coldspringfactory#.loadBeansFromXmlFile( beanDefinitionFile="#fb_.verbInfo.beans[fb_.i]#" ) />');
    }
```

Now I know that **coldspring.beans.DefaultXmlBeanFactory**  has now moved to **coldspring.beans.xml.XmlBeanFactory**, but the problem is that **loadBeansFromXmlFile** no longer exists.

Is there an equivalent in version 2.0?  Should I be editing this file at all?

thanks

Comment: You might not want to use ColdSpring 2. It was only ever released as 'alpha' - and that was 2 years ago.

Comment: Thanks, I'm beginning to get that...

Comment: Instead of migrating to Coldspring 2.0, you should perhaps consider migrating the whole app to FW/1 with DI/1 or Coldbox with Wirebox.

Comment: You can even use DI/1 or WireBox without using the 'companion' framework. Out of curiosity @user1950053, why do you want to update ColdSpring? Is there a bug causing issues? ColdSpring 1.2 is very stable.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I actually started looking at alternative frameworks, including Coldbox following this.  I was initially concerned that CF10 / Coldspring 1.2 would not play nice (the code analyzer throws up some areas of concern), but now I think it may be OK. Michael

Answer (score 0):

> I actually started looking at alternative frameworks, including Coldbox following this. I was initially concerned that CF10 / Coldspring 1.2 would not play nice (the code analyzer throws up some areas of concern), but now I think it may be OK.